# Cannot instantiate: unexpected 'class_name' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying this script on PHP 7.0, but I cannot instantiate. I've reviewed time after time, but I cannot figure out where is the error. Please could you help me?

```
<?php
class MiClase
{
    public $var1 = 'Publica';
    protected $var2 = 'Protegida';
    private $var3 = 'Privada';

    public function imprimir()
    {
        echo "Funcion Imprimir:<br>";
        echo $this->var1 . "<br/>";
        echo $this->var2 . "<br/>";
        echo $this->var3 . "<br/>";
        echo "---------------<br/>";
    }
}

$miclase = $new MiClase();
$miclase->imprimir();
echo "var1: ".$miclase->var1 . "<br/>";
echo "var2: ".$miclase->var2 . "<br/>";
echo "var3: ".$miclase->var3 . "<br/>";
```

Comment: `$new`!!! WTF!!! Try simply `new`

Comment: You instantiate the class like `$miclase = new MiClase()`. Notice the lack of dollar sign.

Comment: @Mark Baker Might be worth pointing out why $new is not right.

Answer (score 1):

The error was:

`$miclase = $new MiClase();`

It was without "$" before new!

`$miclase = new MiClase();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use New keyword to instantiate class with out  dollar sign please follow the below code:

```
$miclase = new MiClase();
```

instead of

```
$miclase = $new MiClase();
```